# jQuery carousel next element not sliding in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r0mvyLmx/

I have to write a simple jQuery horizontal carousel from scratch, but I've stumbled into the following issue: when the next button is pressed the current element slides out of view just fine, but the next element does not slide in. It shows up only after the previous element is completely out of view. If you've not understood me, this is the effect I'm after: http://jsfiddle.net/yvD5S/ (next and previous slides sliding at the same time).

Here's my code:

```
    $('#carousel-outer button:last').on('click', function () {
        var slide = $('#carousel-inner .item.active');

        slide.animate({'margin-left':'-480px'},2000,function() {
            slide.css({ 'margin-left': 0 });
            slide.parent().find('div:last').after(slide);
            slide.removeClass('active');
            slide.parent().find('div:first').addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, the issue turned out to be pretty simple. It was not the jQuery, but actually the CSS, that is faulty. On the inner wrapper of the carousel, I had given it the same width of the outer wrapper and the slides weren't displaying inline, but rather block, so they weren't able to flow after one another. I've updated the fiddle for anyone who is interested in the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/r0mvyLmx/1/. There was also a minor change in the JS, in order to keep the inactive elements with display:none.

CSS:

```
#carousel-outer {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

#carousel-inner {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery change:

```
$('#carousel-outer button:last').on('click', function () {
    var slide = $('#carousel-inner .item.active');

    slide.next().addClass('active');
    slide.animate({'margin-left':'-480px'},2000,function() {
        slide.css({ 'margin-left': 0 });
        slide.parent().find('div:last').after(slide);
        slide.removeClass('active');
});
```